# How to get the calculated sell price for the current user?

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

Is there a simple way to get the calculated sell price for the current user?

I try to get it from an implementation of hook_field_formatter_view.

Context: I use multiple rules to alter the base price. Work find but I want to alter the displayed price on product page. Sadly, from my hook implementation, the only price I get is the base price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the tips:
Add this to the array return by my_price_formatters_field_formatter_info() :

```
'settings' => array(
    'calculation' => TRUE,
  ),
```

Like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function my_price_formatters_field_formatter_info() {
    return array(
    'commerce_price_for_me' => array(
      'label' => 'Price my way',
      'field types' => array('commerce_price'),
      'settings' => array(
        'calculation' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then add this function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_form().
 */
function my_price_formatters_field_formatter_settings_form($field, $instance, $view_mode, $form, &$form_state) {
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $element = array();

  switch($display['type']) {
    case 'commerce_price_for_me':
      $element['calculation'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#value' => TRUE,
        '#title' => t('Show calculated price'),
        '#default_value' => empty($settings['calculation']) ? 'TRUE' : $settings['calculation'],
      );
      break;
  }
  return $element;
}
```

And this one too:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_summary().
 */
function my_price_formatters_field_formatter_settings_summary($field, $instance, $view_mode) {
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $summary = array();

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'commerce_price_for_me':
      if ($settings['calculation'] == TRUE){
        $summary[] = 'Show calculated price.';
      } else {
        $summary[] = 'Show base price.';
      }
    break;
  }
  return implode('<br />', $summary);
}
```

Then amount (in $items or $entity) will be the calculated price.

And that's all folks.